# How to tell if the list is empty using "filter" and "map"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
      list
        .filter((val) => {
          if (
            val.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(input))
          ) {
            return val
          }
        })
        .map((val, idx) => (
          <Li
            key={idx}
          />
        ))
```

Using this structure, I wanted to do something if returns empty.

Ex: When searching for "abc" and there is no "abc" in the list, a message appears saying that "abc" was not found.

Comment: `.length === 0`. list is empty

Comment: you can optimise ur filter 
.filter(({ name }) => name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(input))

Answer (score 1):

Several things to change:

#### 1. Your filter expression is only working by accident

```
list
    .filter((val) => {
      if (
        val.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(input))
      ) {
        return val
      }
    })
```

can be just

```
list
    .filter(val => val.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(input)
```

Remember that the function inside `filter` just returns a `true` or `false`. By chance your expression, which returns the actual list element, is interpreted as `true`, and when your expression does not match, you don't return anything, which has the same effect as returning `false`. Expressing it as above makes it clearer what you are doing (and is very marginally faster).

#### 2. To get your error message, save the output of the filter so you can test its length.

```
const matches = list.filter(val => val.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(input)

const output =  (matches.length>0) ? 
    matches.map((val, idx) => (
      <Li
        key={idx}
      />
    )) : (
      <div>Not found</div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell if the list is empty using "filter" and "map" by using following JavaScript Code:

```
list
.filter((value) => (value!==undefined) && (value!==null) && value.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(input)))
.map((value, id) => (
          <Li
            key={id}
          />
))
```